# MS-Access run time error 2046

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error

I am running MS-Access 2000 (not my choice - the company uses it).

I notice that if I have the startup settings set to open a form when the database is opened I get run time error 2046: The command or action 'Requery' isn't available at this time.

I cannot debug it though because when I click debug the database closes and the only time the error occurs is when I'm closing the database.

Does anyone know what triggers this and what I can do to rid of the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you hold the shift key down as you open the database, it will bypass the startup settings and open directly to the database window. You can then look at the form to see what is causing the problem. There is either a macro or a VBA event procedure behind the form that is trying to Requery the form at the wrong time.